# Android Java compare String with EntityUtils.toString(HttpEntity)

Tags: java, android

I have written following code to **POST** data to service from **Native Android**. The service returns response string as **"successfully added"** which I need to compare to ensure that call to the service has successfully completed.

But when I compare this response string to hard coded string **"successfully added"**, it goes into *else* part but still prints "successfully added" in the *else* part. By that logic it should go to *if* part.

I am not able to get this behavior. The code is working fine. But I need the flow should go into *if* part and should print **"yes"** to the console.
Some help would be appreciated.

```
    String str_ajax_result = "successfully added";

    HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String URL = "http://service_url";

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);

    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(ja.toString(),"UTF-8");
    se.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    httppost.setEntity(se);

    HttpResponse res = Client.execute(httppost);

    str_ajax_result = EntityUtils.toString(res.getEntity());

    Log.v("result", str_ajax_result); // prints "successfully added" to console

   if (str_ajax_result.equals("successfully added")) {
        Log.v("yes", "yes")
    } else {
        Log.v("no", str_ajax_result); // prints "successfully added" to console
    }
```

Comment: Please post the actual LogCat for the console. In particular, differences in spacing or capitalization might be an issue.

Comment: Probably you are getting more chars from `res.getEntity()` so check length of both strings  `str_ajax_result.length()`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K thanks, it worked. I got quotes at start and end.